# Как сделать функцию перевода на aiogram python с помощью TextBlob

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно сделать функцию перевода без выбора языков используя TextBlob.

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    msg.text.translate(to='en')
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)
```

Основная функция перевода. Не рабочая.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как функцию перевода text.translate(to='en') запихать в @dp.message_handler()